How to write nest numpy type hint
The numpy type hints I wrote don't work as I expected.
I have a ndarray
 [
 [ 894.45481226  279.40789779  989.63422511  296.75358057]
 [1546.42116975   57.95559617  754.60849398  482.2156838 ]
 [1615.88569942  497.95665529 1642.07014504  253.87915567]
 [ 218.7096641  1212.50328182 1117.34125593  904.91145497]
 ]

And I tried to write hint like numpy.typing.NDArray[numpy.typing.NDArray[numpy.float64]],but Pylance tell me
Could not specialize type "NDArray[ScalarType@NDArray]"
  Type "NDArray[float64]" cannot be assigned to type "generic"
    "NDArray[float64]" is incompatible with "generic"

I'm not sure if there is a way to  make it correct.

That's a numpy.typing.NDArray[numpy.float64] with shape [4, 4]. The shape describes the nesting rather than the type. That is, more nesting will change the shape. It will always have type numpy.typing.NDArray[numpy.float64]. I don't believe you can encode the shape in the types without third party tools
